# Class of a generic Java type cannot be assigned to a variable whose Class type is upper bounded by a generic super type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, upperbound

I use Java 8. In my design a have a few simple classes which model value parameters such as `FloatParameter` or `EnumParameter<E>`. A have a common generic super class of these classes (`GenericParameter<T>`) which implements parameter name and its default value. The sub classes implement other attributes specific to them such as range in case of `FloatParameter`.

Moreover, I want to work with the types of the parameters regardless of their specific type. But I still want to bound the types in the way that they are sub types of `GenericParameter<T>`. In order to do that, I created a method such as `process(Class<? extends GenericParameter<?>> paramType)`.

Now, the problem is that the `EnumParameter.class` **cannot** be assigned to a variable of type `Class<? extends GenericParameter<?>>` while `FloatParameter.class` **can** be.

Further I list the code for the classes to make it more clear and reproducible:

```
public class GenericParameter<T> {
    protected String name;
    protected T defaultValue;
}

public class FloatGenericParameter extends GenericParameter<Float> {
    ...
}

public class TypedGenericParameter<T> extends GenericParameter<T> {
    ...
}

Class<? extends GenericParameter<?>> fgpc = FloatGenericParameter.class; // ok
Class<? extends GenericParameter<?>> tgpc = TypedGenericParameter.class; // error: incompatible types: Class<TypedGenericParameter> cannot be converted to Class<? extends GenericParameter<?>>
Class<? extends GenericParameter> tgpc2 = TypedGenericParameter.class; // warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: GenericParameter
```

Finally, when using a non-generic base class, there is no problem:

```
public class Parameter {
    ....
}

public class FloatParameter extends Parameter {
    ...
}

public class TypedParameter<T> extends Parameter {
    ...
}

Class<? extends Parameter> fpc = FloatParameter.class; // ok
Class<? extends Parameter> tpc = TypedParameter.class; // ok
```

Please, do you have any suggestions?

I can go with `process(Class<?> paramType)` as a workaround or do casts, but I wanted to benefit from the static type checking by the compiler.

EDIT:

I would like to use the cast when registering factories that produce GUI components for each parameter type. The code looks like:

```
addParameterComponentFactory(EnumParameter.class, new ParameterComponentFactory() { ... })
```

In such case, the compiler would check the added parameter type at compile time. Also the code would be more self-explaining.

EDIT 2:

Currently, I am using the suggested approach to introduce a type parameter for the `addParameterComponentFactory` method. The signature looks like this:

```
public static <P extends GenericParameter<?>> addParameterComponentFactory(Class<P> clazz, ParameterComponentFactory pcf)
```

With this definition I am able to specify `TypedParameter.class` (`EnumParameter.class` - also one type param) as well as I obtain the static type checking.

Comment: Please can you post some code where you need to cast `TypedGenericParameter.class` to `Class<? extends GenericParameter<?>>`?

Comment: Hi, I tried to add an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the core bits of your API.  You have a generic `Parameter<T>`
type that represents some named parameter with a value of type `T`.  You have
specialized GUI components designed to edit or display specific types of
parameters, and you want to be able to register factories to create these
components.

```
class Parameter<T> {
    String name;
    T defaultValue;
}

class ParameterComponent<P extends Parameter> {
    void setParameter(final P p) {}
}

interface ParameterComponentFactory<P extends Parameter> {
    ParameterComponent<P> newComponent();
}

class FloatParameter extends Parameter<Float> {}
class FloatParameterComponent extends ParameterComponent<FloatParameter> {}

class EnumParameter extends Parameter<Enum> {}
class EnumParameterComponent extends ParameterComponent<EnumParameter> {}
```

If I understand you correctly, you're running into trouble figuring out how to
declare a method that statically enforces a relationship between some
`Parameter` type and a factory for GUI components specialized for that type.
For example, you want to be able to write this:

```
addComponentFactory(EnumParameter.class, EnumParameterComponent::new);    // OK
addComponentFactory(FloatParameter.class, FloatParameterComponent::new);  // OK
addComponentFactory(FloatParameter.class, EnumParameterComponent::new);   // ERROR!
```

The problem is related to the rules of generic subtyping, and you can work around them by employing a type variable instead of an embedded wildcard.  This should give you the type checking you want, without the need for
nasty casting:

```
static <P extends Parameter> void addComponentFactory(
    final Class<P> parameterType,
    final ParameterComponentFactory<? extends P> factory) { ... }
```

---

#### Explanation<sup>[1]</sup>

> Explain the difference between introducing a new type `P extends Parameter<?>` used in `Class<P>` and stating
>   directly `Class<? extends Parameter<?>>`

This is complicated, so bear with me.  Let's talk a bit about wildcards, raw
types, and conversions.  Consider the following:

```
// Scenario 1(a)
GenericParameter raw = /* some value */;
GenericParameter<?> wc = raw;

// Scenario 1(b)
Class raw = GenericParameter.class; 
Class<?> wc = raw;

// Scenario 2
Class<GenericParameter> classOfRaw = GenericParameter.class; 
Class<GenericParameter<?>> classOfWC = classOfRaw;
```

Scenarios 1(a) and 1(b) both compile for the same reason: because a raw type
`G` may undergo an [unchecked conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)
to any parameterized type of the form `G<T_1, ..., T_n>`.

Scenario 2 does **NOT** compile.  But why?

In Scenario 2, neither side in the second assignment is a raw type. For the
[assignment to be valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2),
there must be either an identity conversion or a [*widening* conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)
from the right-hand type to the left-hand type.  For widening conversions on
reference types, the left-hand type must be a supertype of the right-hand type.
When these types are generic, the rules of [generic subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)
apply.  Specifically, the type arguments on the left-hand side must
*[contain](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)*
the type arguments on the right-hand side.

An assignment from `Class<String>` to `Class<? extends Object>` is valid.
`Class<String>` is a generic subtype of `Class<? extends Object>` because
`? extends Object` *contains* `String`.  In Scenario 2, for the second
assignment to be valid, `GenericParameter<?>` would have to contain
`GenericParameter`, but it doesn't.  `T` is **not** a subtype of `T<?>`;
`T` is a *supertype* of `T<?>`.  Thus, by the generic subtyping rules,
`Class<T>` is not a subtype of `Class<T<?>>`, and the assignment is not
valid.

So why does the following work?

```
public static <P extends GenericParameter<?>> addParameterComponentFactory(
    Class<P> clazz, 
    ParameterComponentFactory pcf)

addParameterComponentFactory(EnumParameter.class, new ParameterComponentFactory() {})
```

In the call above, type inference on `P` is driven entirely by the 
`Class<P>` argument.  You are passing a `Class<EnumParameter>`, so `P`
in this case gets bound to the raw type `EnumParameter`.  For the constraint
`P extends GenericParameter<?>` to be satisfied, `GenericParameter<?>`
must be assignable from `EnumParameter`, and it is assignable via an
unchecked conversion, just like in Scenarios 1(a) and 1(b).

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> This explanation is <strike>blatant plagarism</strike>
an amalgamation of other excellent Stack Overflow answers, mostly by
[radiodef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2891664/radiodef).</sub>

Comment: Wow, the addition of the type parameter to the `addComponentFactory` solved the problem. But, could you please explain the difference between introducing a new type parameter `P extends Parameter<?>` used in `Class<P>` and stating directly `Class<? extends Parameter<?>>`?

Comment: I didn’t use `Parameter<?>` as my upper bound; I used `Parameter`.  So there are really two questions: (1) why use a raw type in the upper bound, and (2) why use a generic parameter instead of wildcards?  I will attempt to answer both once I have had breakfast and some caffeine :).

Comment: Sure. I was aware of raw `Parameter`, but I used `Parameter<?>` as the upper bound and it works nicely since the compiler does not complain about `rawtype`. I could comment on that, sorry.

Comment: And that worked?  Would you mind showing me the signature for your add method, and the declaration of your factory class?  (Just append to the bottom of your question.)

Comment: Sure, I added it as EDIT 2.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Even after years of writing Java code, and even writing a Java decompiler, I still have trouble grasping some of the nuances of generics, especially where wildcards are concerned.  Hopefully my addendum is both useful and correct.